# Disconnected asterisk calls manually

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asterisk

I am using the below code to hangout the asterisk calls using c#. But its not working calls not disconnected.Please help me to do this.I am using the same method to login asterisk.But its working.

```
if (this.parser == null)
{
    this.parser = new ProtocolParser();
    this.parser.Parsed += new ProtocolParser.OnParsed(ParserParsed);
}

if (this.socketmanager == null)
{
    this.socketmanager = new SocketManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SERVER_LISTEN_IP"], 8999); 

    this.socketmanager.Connected += new SocketManager.OnConnected(SocketManagerConnected);
    this.socketmanager.Disconnected += new SocketManager.OnDisconnected(SocketManagerDisconnected);
    this.socketmanager.DataArrival += new SocketManager.OnDataArrival(SocketManagerDataArrival);
    this.socketmanager.SocketError += new SocketManager.OnSocketError(SocketManagerSocketError);
    socketmanager.Connect();
}

if (this.parser != null & this.socketmanager != null)
{
    //Extnston = txt_agentex.Text;
    string application = string.Empty;
    application = "Hangup";
    string cmd = "Hangup/SIP/10.xxx.xx.xx-0000003d|1395833122.145|21";
    ExtnStrg = "IAX2/" + Extnston;

    if (this.socketmanager.SendData(cmd))
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>show('success','" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SUCS-WLK"].ToString() + "');</script>", false);
    }
    else
    {
         this.socketmanager.Disconnect();
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>show('error','" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ERROR-AUT"].ToString() + "');</script>", false);
         return;
    }
    //this.socketmanager.Disconnect();               
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your cmd from asterisk's CLI which is full working ?

Comment: Ok, but you can hangup call from CLI ? Now Im looking into my CLI and see right syntax to hangup which is 'hangup request CHANNEL_ID'

Answer (score 0):

For 1.6+ version:

```
pro-sip*CLI> channel request hangup 
Usage: channel request hangup <channel>|<all>
       Request that a channel be hung up. The hangup takes effect
       the next time the driver reads or writes from the channel.
       If 'all' is specified instead of a channel name, all channels
       will see the hangup request.
```